# base64 syntax for sending attachments in Thunderbird with HTML

Tags: html, email, base64, png, html-email

to follow up with how to [send](https://superuser.com/q/1218099/55747) base64 images in Thunderbird signatures:

```
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ cat .tbird/sig.html

<b>thufir</b>
<br><img moz-do-not-send="true" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAA
ANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4
//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU
5ErkJggg==" 

style="height:836px; width:592px"
alt="Signature"/>



thufir@doge:~$
```

yet, this sends "Signature", the `alt` text.  Is there a syntax problem?

The `base64` is from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#HTML).

the dot, while oversized, displays:

[image]

The full message in Thunderbird:

```
Return-Path: <hawat.thufir@gmail.com>
Received: from [192.168.1.7] ([<my_ip>])
        by smtp.gmail.com with ESMTPSA id x73sm12753514pfa.71.2017.06.11.00.12.30
        for <hawat.thufir@gmail.com>
        (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Sun, 11 Jun 2017 00:12:30 -0700 (PDT)
To: hawat.thufir@gmail.com
From: thufir <hawat.thufir@gmail.com>
Subject: red dot
Message-ID: <9d3ddf68-60ce-63ee-c36d-2bd814322144@gmail.com>
Date: Sun, 11 Jun 2017 00:12:28 -0700
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101
 Thunderbird/45.7.0
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8; format=flowed
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

no red dot


-- 
*thufir*
altsig
```

Comment: Can you try without `moz-do-not-send="true"`?

Comment: it's the same result.  I've tried `false` and `true` also.

Comment: Okay. In your email client try viewing the original HTML of the email.

Comment: The image you are [referring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme#HTML) to is not actually a dot. Try zoom in and see.

Comment: I resized, looks more like a cross now.

Comment: Continue discussion here [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60262/discussion-between-thufir-and-codeit)

Answer (score -1):

syntax is fine (had boolean reversed, but that's incidental):

```
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ cat .tbird/sig.html

this is in <i>italics</i>
<br>
and something <em>emphasized</em>
<br>
here's some <b>bold</b>

<br>
<br>
<br>

<img moz-do-not-send="false" src="data:image/png;base64,
iVBORw0KGgoAAA
ANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4
//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU
5ErkJggg==" 

style="height:22px; width:22px"
alt="Signature"/>

thufir@doge:~$
```

forgot to enable HTML e-mail:

https://askubuntu.com/q/100797/45156